# Highcharts column with drilldown results in blurred data label in main chart, except for the drilled down columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

When coding a Column Chart with Drilldown:

The main chart rendered blurred black colored data labels. But when they are clicked, the next columns (the drilled down columns that are opened) are perfect (white color, no blur, very readble).
I found a workaround declaring:

```
.highcharts-drilldown-data-label TEXT { color: #FFFFFF !important; text-shadow: 0 0 0px white !important; fill: white !important }
```

Try to remove the selector above and check the result: https://jsfiddle.net/marcelbonnet/pjb5dw9q/1/

Now, is it a bug in highcharts or perhaps some mistake of mine? I even tryed change jQuery version, but no effects.

Comment: Which browser do you use? I tested in the newest Chrome and labels are printed properly with shadow.

Comment: @SebastianBochan, sorry for the long delay. I was using Chrome 28, but recently upgraded to 48 . Same problem removing the CSS selector.

Answer (score 2):

*(I would comment, but I dont have enough points.)*

To me it looks like a bug. If you do not include the `drilldown.js` your fiddle works as expected. I would run with the css.

Note that the fiddle doesn't work in FF unless the `TEXT` is in lowercase:

```
.highcharts-drilldown-data-label text {...}
```

You might want do report the bug at https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues

Comment: you're right, the selector shall be in lowercase for FF . Done: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5145

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED with a hand from highcharts support on github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5145#issuecomment-200878598

An example here: https://jsfiddle.net/pjb5dw9q/6/

The problem is related to the style , because by default it is underlined and blue to invite to interaction. See api.highcharts.com/highcharts#drilldown.activeDataLabelStyle .

Adding the code below solved it to me.

```
drilldown: {
                activeDataLabelStyle: {
                                color: 'blue' //style to invite interaction
            },
```